# How get input text changer with [IONIC,javascript,HTML,cordova]

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm starting to learning javascript.
I'm fallowing a tutoriel but version of IONIC has been updated so directory and folder are not the same. also template has changer.

For each page of app, i have : one *.html, one *.scss and and *.ts (NOT *.js)

So I have some dificutly to developpe the app.
I try to add a function, this function should get "username" value after change and show this using alert popup
Actually my code show the text value of username but only the default value  ="#" , if I change and presse 'enter' popup show "username = #"

So which attribute a can use or something to get current value and not default value.

Note: If you have a good course/tutoriel with last version on IONIC, i'm interested ;)

HTML part of login.html

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
        <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
<!--    <script src="login.js"></script>-->
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

    <form id="myForm">
        <input id="username" title="Username" type="text" placeholder="Username" value="#"   (change)="testUserName()"  >
    </form>

</ion-content>
```

Script part of login.ts

```
import {
    Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    NavController
} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
})

export class LoginPage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {    
    }
    public testUserName(): void {
        var username = document.getElementById('username');
        alert('username = '+ username.getAttribute("value"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess You are working with Ionic 3 app which uses typescript (.ts) rather than .js file. IONIC 3 framework works on top of typescript and angular 2/4. So in order to get the changed values in your input you can bind your html view with your component file (ts file). You can use [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#how-to-use) to do the binding. Try this :

```
 <form id="myForm">
    <input id="username" title="Username" type="text" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="userName"   (change)="testUserName()"  >
</form>
```

in .ts file

```
export class LoginPage {
userName:string; // you can also give default value here
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {    
}
public testUserName(): void {
    alert('username = '+this.userName); // see same ngModel binded in HTML
}
  }
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thank a lot, it was very helpful :)  I'm precised my "final" code below

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot, it was very helpful :)
I have to add "name" attribue in html file. I was this error

```
     Runtime Error Uncaught (in promise): Error: If ngModel is used within
     a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control
     must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions. 
Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first"> 
Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

So my working code is:

In *.html file

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="username" title="Username" type="text" placeholder="Username"  [(ngModel)]="userName" name="username" (change)="testUserName()"  >
</form>
```

In *.ts file

```
export class LoginPage {
    userName: string; // you can also give default value here
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }
    public testUserName(): void {
        alert('username = ' + this.userName); // see same ngModel binded in HTML
    }
}
```